# html src hidden

Tags: java, javascript, html, httpclient, hidden

Trying to read a webpage using HttpClient. But some of the html is hidden by some js magic, try hitting view source on this page `http://uc.worldoftanks.eu/uc/accounts/#wot&at_search=a`
Any idea how to get HttpClient to return the "full" html page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HttpClient` does not process javascript, which means there is no content that can be hidden when reading the http content from the server.

It's probably the other way round, the javascript that runs on the page likely *creates* new html elements and appends them to the DOM... which is not something you can handle using `HttpClient`, `HttpClient` is a communication client designed purely to read data accross a HTTP connection.

Comment: @martin: as far as I can tell, the only data that's being added after page load is the table data, which you can still get quite easily by querying another address; see my post.

Answer (score 0):

When that page loads, a request is being sent to
http://uc.worldoftanks.eu/uc/accounts/?type=table&offset=0&limit=25&order_by=name&search=a&echo=1&id=accounts_index

Try hitting that address up with your HttpClient to see the table data. Play with the `offset`, `limit` and `order_by` values to change pagination and sorting.

Manually browsing to said URL yields a redirect, though, so there appears to be some of the Request headers that you need to include in your HttpClient. The full headers of the request my browser issues, that does yield a JSON response with the table data, is as follows:

```
GET /uc/accounts/?type=table&offset=0&limit=25&order_by=name&search=&echo=1&id=accounts_index HTTP/1.1
Host: uc.worldoftanks.eu
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://uc.worldoftanks.eu/uc/accounts/?type=table&offset=0&limit=25&order_by=name&search=a&echo=1&id=accounts_index
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-CSRFToken: 5e33bf57602f76de9285e9b14bcfe7fe
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.107 Safari/535.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,ar;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: csw_popup=true; __utma=21812543.1316104722.1312873581.1312873581.1312873581.1; __utmb=21812543.2.10.1312873581; __utmc=21812543; __utmz=21812543.1312873581.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); csrftoken=5e33bf57602f76de9285e9b14bcfe7fe
```

They might be looking for `X-Requested-With` or `Accept` or `Referrer`, for instance.